# C# program stopped execution while converting LINQ Date to string

Tags: datetime, entity-framework-6

I am working on C# with entity framework 6.
when my program control reaches following line of code.

```
Date= j.Date.Value.ToShortDateString()
```

it stops its execution..

Following is Entity Frame work Join Query Code

```
            SCIMSEntities db = new SCIMSEntities();
        var list = from i in db.tblVendors
                join j in db.tblVendorPaymentBillsHistories on i.Id equals j.Vendor_Id
                select new clsAddBillToVendor
                {
                    id= j.Id,
                    CompanyName= i.CompanyName,
                    BillNo= j.BillNo,
                    Details= j.Details,
                    BilllAmount= j.BillAmount.Value,
                    Date= j.Date.Value.ToShortDateString(),
                    TotalAmount= j.TotalAmount.Value
                };
             return list;
```

Comment: your program stops execution at a point of a seemingly extension function call. how come you don't show us that function and expect the question to be solved?

Answer (score 1):

I have found error. when control comes to this lines to execute

```
    Date= j.Date.Value.ToShortDateString()
```

but value is already in SQL Server Database is in ShortDate Format. I think DateTime class has no definition or exception handle mechanism to Convert Already short DateTime to Short DateTime Format. So it Stopped its execution.
I Just removed "ToShortDateString()" from the code.my new code line was

```
    Date= j.Date.Value;
```

Every thing is working well know

Answer (score 0):

You can't use string functions in LINQ to Entities so you need to make an IEnumerable so you can use LINQ to Entities:

```
        SCIMSEntities db = new SCIMSEntities();

        var (list = from i in db.tblVendors
            join j in db.tblVendorPaymentBillsHistories on i.Id equals j.Vendor_Id
            select new clsAddBillToVendor
            {
                j.Id,
                i.CompanyName,
                j.BillNo,
                j.Details,
                j.BillAmount,
                j.Date,
                j.TotalAmount
            })
         .AsEnumerable()
         .Select(x => new clsAddBillToVendor
                {
                    x.Id,
                    x.CompanyName,
                    x.BillNo,
                    x.Details,
                    x.BillAmount,
                    Date = x.Date.Value.ToShortDateString(),
                    x.TotalAmount
                })
         .ToList();

         return list;
```